# how to create a multi field query in access 2007?

Tags: mysql, sql

guys
' i am beginner in access 2007 and i want to create a form that contains many fields (product id, product name, etc and date of transaction) and use a query to search for data
in other words for example i want to enter in this form a date range i.e from 1/1/2013 to 1/03/2013 and search for product x ( attention ) my basic table contains only date of transacton field and not the from, to fields ( the from , to fields i want only to add them in the search form and them to search based on the value or date of transaction field ) please help me

Answer (score 0):

Short but sweet answer;

Create a new "Query" using the GUI.  Add your table to the top part.  Double-click columns in the table to add them to the output of the Query.

Next, in the query conditions (grid below the name of each field) use brackets "[]" around your from/to dates.  E.g. the query condition underneath your date field may be;

"between [MyStartDate] and [MyEndDate]".

Now "run" the query to test it; Access will prompt you for 'MyStartDate' and 'MyEndDate'.

Finally; if you save this query and set it as the "Data Source" for a Form, you may alter the above condition slightly to pull the values automatically from the form itself, so that you are not prompted every time the query runs. E.g. this condition may be;

"between Forms![MyTableForm]![MyStartDate] and Forms![MyTableForm][MyEndDate]".

You will have to play with it a little, but those are the basics.